# Pass a JSP variable as parameter to javascript function

Tags: jsp

I have a function defined inside the script tags of head.(in a JSP)
I want to declare a string variable in the JSP and pass it as a parameter to this function

```
<%  String uname ="multiple"; %>
<form action="ExampleServlet" method="post" onclick="pagetype(${uname});"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Log in" value="Login" />
</form>
```

But this doesn't work.
need Help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use like this

```
<% String uname ="multiple"; %>
<form action="ExampleServlet" method="post" onclick="pagetype('<%=uname%>');"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Log in" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yes @AdrienBe, i do agree, but for the OP it is the answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to avoid scirplet, you can use expression language by putting it between single quotes.

```
onclick="pagetype('${uname}')";
```

without the quotes, it tries to look for a variable with name same as the value of uname.

PS: Used the chrome/firefox dev-tools debugging to find out what's going wrong.