# Passing Jsp variable to javascript as a function parameter

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have the same query as.
[Pass a JSP variable as parameter to javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033555/pass-a-jsp-variable-as-parameter-to-javascript-function)
However, If i use `onclick="pagetype('<%=uname%>');` i'm getting illegal start of type error. Please help to fix this.

Yes.. <%@ page contentType= "text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

Answer (score 0):

Have you put the end double quote?

`onclick="pagetype('<%=uname%>')"`

The error is a javascript error ? If it is, Is <%=uname%> visible in the page source?

Have you put something like `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>` at the top of the jsp?

Comment: Yes.. <%@ page contentType= "text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

Comment: <%@ page language="java" contentType= "text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

Comment: <%@ page language="java" contentType= "text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ page import =="java.util.Date,java.text.SimpleDateFormat,java.text.ParseException"%>
<%@page import= "java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit" %>
<%@ include file="dbconnect.jsp" %>
<html>
<% --Connection to db-- while (rsp.next()){String date1 = rsp.getString("p");out.println(date1)}%>
<body><form action="" method="post" onsubmit="alert2('<%=date1');">
 </html>

Comment: <script>function alert2(getid){ var id=get id; window.alert(id);}</script>

Comment: If I'm passing some sting instead of <%=date1%> its working fine.

Comment: Ya I was using <%=date1%>. but same error. But instead of sending a jsp variable, if I use a sting like onsubmit="alert2('sample');" then it working.

Answer (score 0):

1. `String date1` is inside a loop. You won't be able to get its value outside.
2. change `alert2('<%=date1');` to `alert2('<%= date1 %>');`