# Pass a foreach JSP variable as parameter to javascript function

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have the following code sample which was written in the JSP. But it is not working. I have tried that code snippet from the following links. But it didn't help me to solve the problem.

[Pass a JSP variable as parameter to javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033555/pass-a-jsp-variable-as-parameter-to-javascript-function)

[Passing Jsp variable to javascript as a function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984291/passing-jsp-variable-to-javascript-as-a-function-parameter)

< c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">

```
   <div onclick="myOnClick('<%=item%>')">${item.title}</div>
```

< /c>

```
function myOnClick(item){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
}
```

Actually I am getting an error in the eclipse that "item cannot be resolved to a variable" for the JSP code.

I tried the below one code

```
      <div onclick="myOnClick(${item})">${item.title}</div>
```

It was throwing "Syntax error:illegal character" error.

Need help to fix this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Why use `<%=item%>` instead of `${item}`?? Anyway, what you insert is a string (you even quoted it with `'`), which is retrieved by calling `item.toString()`, so what is it you expect that `stringify()` call to do? I mean, it's already a string, and very likely not a JSON string, unless you implemented `toString()` to return JSON.

Comment: Actually I am getting an error in the eclipse that "item cannot be resolved to a variable". That is my problem. That method myOnClick() is a temporary method. Don't concentrate on that method implementation. I was asking about the JSP code

Comment: That's a totally different question. Use `${item}`.

Comment: I tried ${item} also. It was throwing "Syntax error:illegal character" error

Comment: On the `${item}` when `${items}` is working fine on the line above?? I find that very hard to believe. Or are you **now** talking about the web browser, not the JSP (because you forgot the add the `'` quotes)??

Comment: Yes. In the web browser only I am testing this page. I am receiving items array properly. After that ${item.title} also coming. But this onclick event is giving the problem.

Comment: So first it's a question about the JavaScript function, except it's a question about an error in the JSP you hadn't shared, except it's a question about a JavaScript syntax error you hadn't shared, except... *<sigh>* Look at the generated source (view source in browser) to see what you did wrong. I'm done helping when you can't even describe your problem.

Comment: I found the answer by my own from the following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577246/how-to-access-a-java-object-in-javascript-from-jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by my own from the following link.

[How to access a java object in javascript from JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577246/how-to-access-a-java-object-in-javascript-from-jsp)

That is what exactly I was doing in the code. I am getting the Java objects and I am mapping them to the HTML. Once they mapped I wan unable to access them from javascript. But in the above link they have provided the solution to the problem. So we have to call a web service to get the actual object. Thank you @LeleDumbo for providing the answer.